# What noun describes one's manner of walking ("gait"?)

Tags: vocabulary

Can I apply the word "gait" when I describe someone's manner of walking? What is the appropriate term? For example:

> He walked with a slow stiff gait.
>
> Larry David walks with a teenagerish gait.

Comment: Larry walks like a teenager

Comment: Or, _Larry **trudges** like a teenager_. Or, if you like Jay's interpretation, _Larry **bounces** like a teenager when he walks_. As for the first sentence, you could say, *He lumbered along, slowly and stiffly*. While you certainly _can_ use "gait" as a noun in this context, some sentences might sound better if you simply used a more descriptive verb in lieu of "walk".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Absolutely.  'One's manner of walking' makes for an effective lay definition of the word *gait*.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gait):  Gait is the pattern of movement of the limbs of animals, including humans, during locomotion over a solid substrate.

I don't however, know that teenagers have a particular gait of their own.  In the second instance I would aim for an adjective that more closely describes types of actions (rather than types of people) eg tireless, frisky, upbeat.

Comment: Interestingly, that I spoke with a couple of Americans and I was under impression that not just this word is not popular but the term itself. It seems you don't characterize people by their gait, as we do in my country.

Comment: Probably sounds too much like Gay - a problematic word in the US it seems. Google nGram does not agree with your findings: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+gait&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: @Graduate As an American: I think it is rare to refer to a person's gait, we're more apt to talk about a horse's gait. I think we'd be more likely to say "he walks in such-and-such a manner" than "he has such-and-such a gait". But if I did read a mention of "Mr Smith's gait", I don't think I'd find it odd or hesitate over it. It's slightly unusual, but not jarring.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see your problem with "teenagerish gait". I'd take that to mean "youthful, energetic". Surely teenagers DO walk differently than old people. As an old person myself, I'm well aware that I don't have the youthful gait that I used to!

Comment: @Jay: I once had a professor with a surprisingly youthful gait. There was quite a spring in his step. We grad students affectionately called him "Be-bop".

Comment: He walked with the slouching gait of a bored and disaffected teenager.  :)

Comment: @BobRodes Well, sure. For any broad generalization like that, there are bound to be exceptions. Like if you said, "He had the strength of a lion", I'd understand you to mean "he was very very strong", even if the last lion that I saw at the zoo was so sick that he was barely able to stand.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this used in medical context, for example festinating gait.
"The patient is exhibiting a festinating gait." (In that context meaning he is exhibiting a particular gait typical for parkinsons disease.)